# QGIS 2.4: How to get Atlas to print all features not just the one visible in preview

Tags: qgis, atlas

I have a number of "zones" described by polygons that I use to produce a set of larger scale maps that I used to export into a pdf.

This has stopped working (when I moved to 2.4 ??) and now I always get just one item in the pdf (the one currently visible in preview).  Each item consists of two pages:  A map on the first page and two tables on the second page.  The idea being that when one prints the pdf two sided then you get a map and the tables on the back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually worked out the answer while composing the questions but I am sure others will get tripped up with this so I decided to continue.

The confusion arises because (at least on Mac ) there ate two sets of export symbols:
[image: mac screen shot]

Note pdf is missing from the second row.  The ones on the top row appear to export the feature currently previewed.  If you click on the image option in the second row then you have the option of selecting pdf.  This does what I want.

I find this arrangement very counter intuitive!  Surely the icons on the preview bar should print the previewed image and the ones on the main bar print the whole set.  Actually the second set does not appear until you select Atlas->Preview Atlas.

Or is this a bug rather than a feature?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Will check it.

Comment: The top export buttons should export the whole set.  The preview button will export a single feature.

Comment: That's what I would expect.  May be it is Mac specific?

Comment: I think so, that button should also have a dropdown normally.

Comment: I have logged a bug report http://hub.qgis.org/issues/11500